# File operation error on windows network drives

Tags: c, windows

Recently I have problems with low-level file oprations (in old legacy code)

```
fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
...
lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_END);
write(fd, buffer, len);
...
lseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
read(fd, buffer, len);
```

on Windows 10 (client), if the file is on a shared network drive provided by e.g. Windows Server 2012 or 2016.
In case of Windows Server 2012 the SMB version of the connection is 3.02, for Windows Server 2016 it is 3.1.1.

The error does not occur every time or at the same position, sometimes the return values of lseek() indicate an error, but most of the times it seems that lseek() does not return the right EOF position, or that the write() operation at EOF was not finished before the next lseek(), kind of a synchronisation/cache problem. Also tried fsync(fd) (or _commit(fd)), O_SYNC, and delays, but it does not seem to be reliable.

With Windows 7 as client it works like it worked for many years on local drives. Also when I mount that drive in Linux, it works with SMB versions 2.1, 3.02, 3.1.1.

So my question is, are there known issues with the SMB protocol, network shares and Windows 10, such that these low-level file operations like lseek() are affected?

UPDATE:

Here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
    #include <io.h>
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define  _O_CREAT   O_CREAT
    #define  _O_RDWR    O_RDWR
    #define  _S_IREAD   S_IREAD
    #define  _S_IWRITE  S_IWRITE
    #define  _open      open
    #define  _write     write
    #define  _lseek     lseek
    #define  _close     close
#endif

char file[] = "file.txt";

int main() {

    int fd = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    int len = 0;
    off_t pos = 0;
    off_t last_eof = 0;
    char buffer[] = "12345";
    int buflen = 0;
    int n = 0;

    buflen = strlen(buffer);

    //unlink(file);

    fd = _open(file, _O_CREAT|_O_RDWR, _S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE);
    if (fd == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR open\n"); exit(1); }

    ret = _close(fd);
    if (ret == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR close\n"); exit(1); }

    for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++)
    {
        fd = _open(file, _O_RDWR, _S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE);
        if (fd == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR open [%d]\n", n); exit(1); }

        pos = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        if (pos == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR lseek1 [%d] pos: %ld\n", n, pos); exit(1); }
        if (last_eof > 0 && pos != last_eof) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR [%d] eof: %ld last_eof: %ld\n", n, pos, last_eof);
            exit(1);
        }

        len = _write(fd, buffer, buflen);
        if (len != buflen) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR write [%d]\n", n); exit(1); }

        pos = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        if (pos == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR lseek2 [%d] pos: %ld\n", n, pos); exit(1); }

        last_eof = pos;

        ret = _close(fd);
        if (ret == -1) { fprintf(stderr, "ERROR close [%d]\n", n); exit(1); }

        if (last_eof != (n+1)*buflen) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR [%d] eof: %ld\n", n, last_eof);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "[%d] EOF: %ld\n", n, last_eof);

    return 0;
}
```

(delete `file.txt` before running!)

Compiled with visual studio, executed on Windows 10 and a network drive it happens that it exits with "eof-error", e.g.

```
> seek5win.exe
ERROR [112] eof: 555 last_eof: 560
```

i.e. the file was closed with eof/size 560, then re-opened with eof/size 555.
If there is no other process accessing the file, it finishes without error. However if the Explorer or some other process scans the directory, the lseek/eof-estimate is sometimes off.
Using `_sopen_s()` with different sh_flags didn't help.

In ProcessMonitor it looks like this (when Explorer and sublime-text come into play):

```
08:41:10,3133  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 540, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,3191  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,3192  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 4.096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,3347  seek5win.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,3460  seek5win.exe  QueryDeviceInformationVolume  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
08:41:10,3594  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 540, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,3643  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 539, Length: 1, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,3644  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 540, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,3754  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 540, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,3838  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 540, Length: 5
08:41:10,4013  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 545, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,4101  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,4102  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 4.096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,4363  seek5win.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,4537  seek5win.exe  QueryDeviceInformationVolume  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
08:41:10,4751  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 545, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,4870  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 544, Length: 1, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,4870  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 545, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,5171  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 545, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,5239  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 545, Length: 5
08:41:10,5375  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 550, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,5475  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,5476  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 4.096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,5646  seek5win.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,5957  seek5win.exe  QueryDeviceInformationVolume  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
08:41:10,6111  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 550, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,6210  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 549, Length: 1, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,6211  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 550, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,6418  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 550, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,6501  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 550, Length: 5
08:41:10,6547  Explorer.exe  QueryDirectory                \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Filter: file.txt, 1: file.txt
08:41:10,6715  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 555, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,6934  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,6935  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 4.096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,6962  Explorer.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,7229  seek5win.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,7408  Explorer.exe  QueryBasicInformationFile     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  CreationTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastAccessTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastWriteTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, ChangeTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, FileAttributes: A
08:41:10,7456  seek5win.exe  QueryDeviceInformationVolume  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
08:41:10,7483  Explorer.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,7585  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 555, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,7645  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 554, Length: 1, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,7646  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 555, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,7886  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 555, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,8013  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 555, Length: 5
08:41:10,8221  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 560, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,8246  sublime_.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,8319  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,8319  seek5win.exe  WriteFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 0, Length: 4.096, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Paging I/O, Synchronous Paging I/O, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,8453  seek5win.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: Open, Options: Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, Write, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,8477  sublime_.exe  QueryBasicInformationFile     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  CreationTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastAccessTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastWriteTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, ChangeTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, FileAttributes: A
08:41:10,8679  seek5win.exe  QueryDeviceInformationVolume  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote
08:41:10,8690  sublime_.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,8843  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 555, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,8918  sublime_.exe  CreateFile                    \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a, OpenResult: Opened
08:41:10,8925  seek5win.exe  ReadFile                      \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  Offset: 554, Length: 1, Priority: Normal
08:41:10,9146  sublime_.exe  QueryBasicInformationFile     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  CreationTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastAccessTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:00, LastWriteTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, ChangeTime: 31.10.2019 08:41:12, FileAttributes: A
08:41:10,9167  seek5win.exe  QueryStandardInformationFile  \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  AllocationSize: 4.096, EndOfFile: 555, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False
08:41:10,9324  sublime_.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS  
08:41:10,9485  seek5win.exe  CloseFile                     \\;LanmanRedirector\...\file.txt  SUCCESS
```

It happens with smb versions 3.02 and 2.1.

On local drives I never observed this. On Windows 7 it runs through the loop without errors on the network drive (other processes scanning the file can make it very slow). On Linux it also works on the network drive (mount -t cifs ..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(partial answer and more details; workaround)

The write() operation updates the current offset in the file. If the write() starts at eof, the new offset becomes the new eof. Another file handle could have a different offset, though the file size and eof should be the same ("global" information) for all.
So if the eof is updated after the current offset is updated for the handle that is writing at eof, and if e.g. the os (or some driver) is not taking further precautions, maybe it could happen that `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` and `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` return different positions.

Here is an update of the example above that shows something like this on Windows 10 and a network drive.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <io.h>

char file[] = "file.txt";

int main() {

    int fd = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    int len = 0;
    off_t pos = 0,
          pos_eof = 0,
          last_pos = 0,
          last_eof = 0;
    char buffer[] = "12345";
    int buflen = 0;
    int n = 0;


    buflen = strlen(buffer);

    //unlink(file);

    fd = _open(file, _O_CREAT|_O_RDWR, _S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE);

    ret = _close(fd);

    for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++)
    {
        fd = _open(file, _O_RDWR, _S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE);

        pos_eof = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        if (last_eof > 0 && pos_eof != last_eof) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR [%d] eof: %ld last_eof: %ld\n", n, pos_eof, last_eof);
            pos = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
            fprintf(stderr, "CUR pos: %ld\n", pos);
            exit(1);
        }

        len = _write(fd, buffer, buflen);

        pos     = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        pos_eof = _lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);

        last_pos = pos;
        last_eof = pos_eof;

        ret = _close(fd);

        if (last_pos != (n+1)*buflen) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR [%d] pos: %ld\n", n, last_pos);
            //exit(1);
        }
        if (last_eof != (n+1)*buflen) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR [%d] eof: %ld (pos: %ld)\n", n, last_eof, last_pos);
            //exit(1);
        }
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "[%d] EOF: %ld\n", n, last_eof);

    return 0;
}
```

Since I never get errors<0 from the file operations, there is no error handling.
If there is no other process touching (reading) the file, it runs without errors. If there is some other process opening the file, I usually get an output like this:

```
ERROR [460] eof: 2295 last_eof: 2300
CUR pos: 2295
```

If I replace the io-functions with windows CreateFile, WriteFile, SetFilePointer, ... (version (b)) it runs a lot faster, but still I get e.g.

```
ERROR [39] eof: 195 (pos: 200)
ERROR [40] eof: 200 last_eof: 195
CUR pos: 200
```

The posix-like calls (that call CreateFile, WriteFile, ...) need more time, and it looks like the file is closed before eof is updated. After re-opening the last 5 bytes are gone.

In the windows-version (b), the windows calls show a difference between the current position and eof, eof is not up-to-date, when SetFilePointer is called a 2nd time in

```
        pos     = SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT); //_lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)
        pos_eof = SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_END); //_lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
```

but after closing the file size is ok.

EDIT:
also posted here

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56f3cdf6-c14b-4053-aaeb-e121706f2866/ioh-file-operations?forum=vcgeneral

UPDATE:

As mentioned in the link above, setting the following win10 registry keys circumvent the problem (as far as I tested...):

```
HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\services\lanmanworkstation\parameters
FileInfoCacheLifetime       REG_DWORD 0x0
FileNotFoundCacheLifetime   REG_DWORD 0x0
DirectoryCacheLifetime      REG_DWORD 0x0
```

Looks like caching parameters for the smb protocol, have to read more about it. I believe the default values are different; it would be nice if it worked without setting these values (to zero).

The workaround is also described here
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_winother-msoversion_other/access-database-is-getting-corrupt-again-and-again/d3fcc0a2-7d35-4a09-9269-c5d93ad0031d?messageId=c9ddd419-da56-42dd-a7ca-f93d29cf2c7f&page=13&auth=1
(a bug in the leasing mode in Windows 10 affects Access Database)

INFO:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/ff686200(v=ws.10)

Comment: Interesting... Your last comment *but after closing the file size is ok* sounds to me like a hint about a caching problem.  The file is cached in memory by the kernel and it looks like it's not handling concurrency properly. When you `close()` the handle, it's flushed, and thus synchronized. Just a thought though...

Comment: Yes, kernel caching is what I suspected. Maybe some other things as someone suggested in the msdn/c++ forum. I didn't get any comments or replies for some time, so I posted it here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56f3cdf6-c14b-4053-aaeb-e121706f2866/ioh-file-operations?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Ont the other hand, the behaviour of the windows-version calling the windows functions CreatFile(),... directly might be acceptable, so perhaps it is the implementation of the posix-like functions _open, _write, ...

Comment: Microsoft was somehow "lazy" with their posix conformance (just as nVidia is with OpenCL vs. Cuda) so they might have done something just for code to compile, without much optimization; but then, it should at least be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Then again the crt is statically linked and I get the same results with different compilers. Thus it is not the crt, if it works on win7.